# Screen always on when on Lightdm login

Tags: lightdm, screensaver

Since updating from 13.04 to 13.10 my monitor when on login screen (Lightdm) is always on and the blank screensaver never works.

Gnome Screensaver is activated and is working find when logged in.

This is bad for electricity consumption

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/403859/19996 (this was asked first, but that one got more attention)