# Stopping screen from going black after lock on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

In Ubuntu 14.04 when I lock my screen it shows my login screen and the background is wisabe, but after couple of seconds the screen goes black.

How can I stop Ubuntu from doing that so that I would see my login screen until I log back in?

Answer (score 3):

The answer actually comes from another question: [How to control LightDM power saving preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403859/how-to-control-lightdm-power-saving-preferences/424954#424954)

```
[...]I've added a script to handle turning off the X dpms timeouts when the user logs in. Here are the three files that I've created. First, the config file:

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-dpms.conf

[SeatDefaults] 
display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/dpms-enable
session-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/dpms-disable

Make sure the above is owned by root. Easiest is to create it with sudoedit.

Next are the two scripts. These need to be owned by root and made executable (chmod +x).

/etc/lightdm/dpms-enable

#!/bin/sh

(
    # This delay is required. Might be because the X server isn't
    # started yet.
    sleep 10

    # Set up a 5 minute timeout before powering off the display.
    xset dpms 0 0 300 
) &

/etc/lightdm/dpms-disable

#!/bin/sh

(
    # This delay is required. Might be because the X server isn't
    # started yet.
    sleep 10

    # Turn off X's handling of dpms timeout. Otherwise
    # gnome-settings-daemon and gnome-screensaver will fight over it.
    xset dpms 0 0 0 
) &

Given the above, I get monitor power-down at the login screen, and the dpms timeouts are set to zero for a user session, so the screensaver works properly.
```

In theory, just set all the values for xset dpms to zero and you should be golden :)