# How to disable sleep/suspend at login screen?

Tags: login, suspend, power-management, login-screen

I've been at trying to do this for the last several hours with no progress.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to disable the sleep/suspend at the login screen (before logging in with any user) so that the display stays active. The suspension/sleep starts after 5 minutes -- a setting I can't seem to find anywhere.

Things that I've tried:

**GUI**

Done for both (all) users:

- Never suspend under Power
- Never turn screen off under Brightness and    Lock.

**Terminal**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
sudo /bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset dpms force off
xset -dpms
```

**crontab -e:**

added

```
@reboot sudo /bin/systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
@reboot /usr/bin/xset s noblank
@reboot /usr/bin/xset s off
@reboot /usr/bin/xset dpms force off
@reboot /usr/bin/xset -dpms
```

**dconf org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power**

```
critical-battery-action nothing
idle-dim false
lid-close-ac-action nothing
lid-close-battery-action nothing
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
sleep-inactive-battery-type nothing
time-critical 36000
time-low 36000
```

(The computer has neither lid nor battery btw)

**sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf**

Added

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option "BlankTime" "0"
  Option "StandbyTime" "0"
  Option "SuspendTime" "0"
  Option "OffTime" "0"
EndSection
```

**Caffeine**

Added

```
@reboot /usr/bin/caffeine &
```

in crontab. Also thought about doing the same with

```
@reboot /usr/bin/caffeine -t 36000
```

but

```
caffeine -t 36000
```

returns

```
usage: caffeinate [-h] [-V] COMMAND [ARGUMENT [ARGUMENT ...]]
caffeinate: error: unrecognized arguments: -t
```

**acpi**

Don't have it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since this question is highly-ranked in search engines, Ubuntu 20.04+ users may additionally wish to investigate this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1045949/how-to-disable-suspend-on-ubuntu-20-04-systemd-via-cli

Comment: Here is a solution: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337649/how-to-disable-suspend-in-20-minutes-from-the-lightdm-login-screen/1338085#1338085](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337649/how-to-disable-suspend-in-20-minutes-from-the-lightdm-login-screen/1338085#1338085)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution from here https://askubuntu.com/a/543861/718511, though they wanted to do the reverse so it's slightly modified. Essentially a script is made to disable dpms and lightdm told to run it.

In **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/** make a file **50-dpms.conf**:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-dpms.conf
```

Add the lines

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/dpms-stop
```

Close the file

In **/usr/local/bin/** create a file **dpms-stop**:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/dpms-stop
```

Add the lines

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo xhost +si:localuser:lightdm # grants localuser rights to X session
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash <<HERE
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
exit
HERE
```

Close the file

Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dpms-stop
```

At reboot it worked for me.

Comment: This indeed works.  Great job! Howver, on most machines you reallyneeds to modify screensaver to:  '''/usr/bin/xset s off'''  ; thus I upvoted  Costa's answer from Jul 21 at 7:10 too.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and found the solution in [this forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398526). Setting the appropriate value using gsettings worked for me. Note that this needs to be set for the `lightdm` user, not for your own account or for `root`. Maybe this was your problem?

Here are the commands you need to run:

```
sudo su
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
exit
exit
```

Note that this only disables sleep for the machine when on AC power. Since I am using a desktop machine, this was sufficient. If you also want to disable sleeping when on battery power, you also need to set the `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout` value to `0`.

After your have run these commands, restart LightDM and you should be good to go.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: If there is a `No protocol specified` error, then execute `export DISPLAY=` before running the `dbus-launch gsettings` command.

Comment: Confirming that this still works, for Ubuntu 20.04 at least. I tried literally everything else, but never thought to try switching to the `lightdm` user. That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was JohanPI's answer, but I had to modify it to turn off the screen saver as well. The modified script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo xhost +si:localuser:lightdm # grants localuser rights to X session
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash <<HERE
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
/usr/bin/xset s off
exit
HERE
```