# Prevent a Workstation Screen from dimming

Tags: suspend, screen

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I would like to prevent my workstation from sleeping even when nobody is logged localy on the machine. This workstation is often used through ssh.

I would like to set that through the command line.

Best regards,
François

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable sleep/suspend at login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942366/how-to-disable-sleep-suspend-at-login-screen)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex The duplicate candidate seems to only address the login screen and not after a user is logged in.

Answer (score 4):

Open the dash and search for power:

[image: Unity dash searching for power]

Open the "Power" option.

Pick the following options:

[image: System power settings set to not suspend or sleep]

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks. But my graphic card makes compiz crash when using the Gnome/Ubuntu desktop. It there a way to do that with command line?

Answer (score 2):

## Terminal CLI method

OP requests a CLI (Command Line Interface) methodology.

### For battery timeout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout <time_in_seconds>
```

### For AC timeout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout <time_in_seconds>
```

So for both Battery and A/C set the time to 0 (never).

### For Login screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Comment: I am not using Gnome but Xfce4 and I need to disable sleep even when nobody is logged in.

Comment: @InsideLoop I think XFCE is based on GNOME. The `gsettings` are persistent across reboots. Try the answer and let me know if it doesn't work. Also is the system suspending or the screen simply turning off when inactive? There is a different setting for that too.

Comment: @InsideLoop I added the login screen to the answer.