# Prevent sleep/suspend when not logged in to a specific account

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

We have a shared office desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 where several jobs (via ssh and screen) often run for weeks on multiple accounts. When logged into an account, sleep/suspend is deactivated through:

1. Power settings in main System Setting
2. Using `gnome-tweak-tool`, setting "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" to off.

This works fine as long as a user with these power settings is always directly logged into the machine (i.e., physically, not via ssh).

The *problem* is when no user is currently logged in directly i.e., when the machine is at the main login screen (like on boot up). There does not appear to be a way to set sleep/suspend settings when not logged into a specific account. So, if the machine remains on this screen, it eventually sleeps, suspending all the running jobs.

As I mentioned, things work fine as long as *some* user is logged in. However, this has been viewed as a security risk. So we'd like to find a better system-wide solution.

I should mention that we have another office desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 which does not have this problem.

Comment: maybe something like this? https://askubuntu.com/a/942987/104223

Comment: If it's a production machine or something critical, you may want to disable suspend completely. That can be done with what Pasi Suominen showed in his answer ( via `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` although not via lidswitch setting). If you do insist on tracking a specific remote login, I think it could be done, but not without root-level service running in background. Disabling suspend globally is an easier solution, and is already available, so I'd recommend that.

Comment: If you want to disable suspend completely, that's doable via policykit. See instructions: https://sites.google.com/site/easytipsforlinux/disable-hibernate-and-suspend

Answer (score 14):

## When no user is signed on

When no user is signed on the power settings come from psuedo-user ID `gdm`. The following controls for **GDM auto-suspend** come from: [ArchLinux GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Setup_default_monitor_settings)

### GDM auto-suspend (GNOME 3.28)

GDM uses a separate dconf database to control power management. You can make GDM behave the same way as user sessions by copying the user settings to GDM's dconf database.

```
$ IFS=$'\n'; for x in $(sudo -u username gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power); do eval "sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set $x"; done; unset IFS
```

where `username` is your user's name.

Or to simply disable auto-suspend (also run the command with ac replaced with battery to also disable it while running on battery):

```
$ sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

Comment: this gives me a lot of "permission denied" error messages

Comment: massive errors here too!

Comment: for me it's: No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power”

Comment: the trick is to first set a gdm password [sudo passwd gdm], like you had to do for your root user to use su, by default gdm had no password for security reasons I guess. After that the "disable auto-suspend" command works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

edit file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

there you can find the line:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

change it to:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

now your login screen ignores your lid switch also.

There is a good ubuntu manual page of logind.conf:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/logind.conf.5.html

To disable suspend via policykit (systemwide setting) follow instructions on:

https://sites.google.com/site/easytipsforlinux/disable-hibernate-and-suspend

Comment: Isn’t reloading systemd required after this? Or will it be picked up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the settings of the user **gdm**.

As **root** execute

```
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 3600
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type "'nothing'"
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 1800
sudo -Hu gdm dbus-launch dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-battery-type "'nothing'"
```

(Probably you don't need the two lines with the timeout.)

Check the settings with

```
sudo -u gdm dconf dump /
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using UBUNTU 18.04 
you can use an indicator named

> **Caffeine Indicator**

you can get it from software store and install it.

Activate it so that it can **Manually control the desktop’s idle state**

Hope so it will help..

Comment: won't this only run when a user is logged in?

Comment: yes  of course you have to log in

Comment: Caffeine is great for "Auto Suspend" ... Enabled or Disabled, but Ubuntu ... gnome on xorg anyway doesn't pay attention to it!