# How to disable sleep at the login screen if no logged in user?

Tags: login, suspend, power-management

I have a latest Ubuntu 20 LTS dekstop with cinnamon UI.
If I turn on my PC but don't log in, my PC go to sleep after a while, getting unreachable via SSH.
I can wake it up by pressing a button on the keyboard locally, but with wake-on-lan.

How I can prevent to go into sleep?

I googled it a lot and tried to set `IdleAction=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and few other things as below, but nothing helped. What else I can do to avoid going into sleep state? I want to reach that PC remotely as well so quite important. Thanks a lot in advance! I guess this is something related to Ubuntu's login screen as logind.conf helped me in case of an Ubuntu server.

```
$ sudo su
# su lightdm -s /bin/bash
# gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd search on systemd, for example in my lubuntu I have the acpid that is running. Then I'd try to disable it with **systemctl disable acpid.service** then try to reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no acpi/acpid service on my PC.

Comment: anyway you have to search in the systemd services. Try to run the following to list the services: **systemctl list-units *.service | grep running**

Comment: I noticed an upower.service I don't know: https://gist.github.com/halacs/1629c1437743ffe1100e2d1f8f6affb7

Comment: I don't find anything of interesting. Then I'd try to search in the "power management" of your windows manager..  for example I have Lubuntu and in the control panel there is the power manager tab to control sleep and hibernate.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-autosuspend.html.en

Comment: Do you think that below X11 related error can block my change? I can reach my PC now only via SSH. I guess it should not.
https://gist.github.com/halacs/fc2a0a95704dd823f4e802071f2310a9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent sleep/suspend when not logged in to a specific account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101043/prevent-sleep-suspend-when-not-logged-in-to-a-specific-account)

Answer (score 0):

I did this :
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'

got it from [Prevent sleep/suspend when not logged in to a specific account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101043)