# Ubuntu Desktop suspending after changing settings not to suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

First time visitor (with an account) and posting.  I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS on a very low cost, Intel based, mini pc, for the purpose of doing some IoT management, running a few low use apps.  Headless config, deployed a "dummy" HDMI connector, no keyboard/mouse.  Use either ssh or remotePC to connect into.  All is working well for my needs, except for the suspend issue.

I do not want this device to suspend - ever.  I have set all settings I can find for the System UI (under power), but when as far as installing/using dconf editor to up values to long times (years) and other settings to never, etc.

This seemed to work, however, only when I am logged in as a user.  If I logout, the device still suspends at ~ 20mins.  My workaround is to log in, lock screen, be done, but I want to resolve this as I may have someone remove/replace power some day.  I don't want them to have a need to login, lock, etc.

Any ideas, pointers to other sites/docs on how to resolve this, i.e. under any circumstance, device should never suspend/hibernate -- my choice.

thanks in advance!

Comment: ** Update **  After more searching, looking at this post and evaluating:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101043/prevent-sleep-suspend-when-not-logged-in-to-a-specific-account

Comment: Additional info needs to be added to the question not made as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in this link:

[Prevent sleep/suspend when not logged in to a specific account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1101043/prevent-sleep-suspend-when-not-logged-in-to-a-specific-account)

Ran this command for both AC and battery:

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'

sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

Rebooted, Ubuntu has been up now for a couple of hours.  I would expect to see the problem in ~20 mins.