# How to disable suspend in 20 minutes from the lightdm login screen?

Tags: suspend, lightdm

Please kindly could you tell how to disable entering the suspend mode in 20 or 30 minutes when the system is idle and the lightdm login screen is active (no user is logged in).

On our machine the diagnostic command gives the following dconf parameters:

```
# sudo -H -u lightdm dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power

org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

The power management module as you see is not active (parameter active is false).

The contents of /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
IdleAction=ignore
IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Please kindly tell where the 20 or 30 min timeout before suspend could be given.

Many thanks in advance.

Ruben Iskandaryan.

Comment: No real solution, but your  are not [alone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942366/how-to-disable-sleep-suspend-at-login-screen) . Excellent question!

Comment: I have added bug description https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1928305

Answer (score 15):

Finally, a solution has been found.

The cause of the problem was that in the system with lightdm and unity-greeter installed as a desktop manager and a greeter respectively timeout intervals are given *twice* as numeric values:

(1) Time before suspend in lightdm.
(2) Time before suspend in unity-greeter.

To change the first set of parameters (for lightdm) I needed to specify the values for
the user lightdm by means of dconf editor:

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
```

I also changed the type of action after the suspend time elapses to 'nothing'

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

To change the second set of parameters (for unity-greeter) I needed to perform a
similar action:

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
```

And

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

Test showed that no further suspend event was observed.

There was no bug, rather simple misunderstanding of that lightdm and unity-greeter store parameters in different places.

With kind regards, Ruben Alexandrovich Iskandaryan.

Comment: Really appreciate you posting this solution